# How to put HTML inside of a jquery or javascript function to to be appended later?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Sorry there might be an answer somewhere out there, but I was having trouble finding it as well as trying to do it myself. But I was wondering if I could get an example of putting HTML inside of a jQuery function as well as a javascript function so that I can use it later to append to DOMs.
**HTML**

```
<div class="container>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function (nothing){
  '<h3>Nothing Here</h3>'
             });

$(".container").append(function(nothing));
```

**RESULT**

```
Nothing Here
```

I am an even bigger noob with javascript, but I'd like to achieve the same result. Can someone show me how? Also, is there a difference in using the javascript method VS the jQuery method? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript answer:
`domElement.innerHTML` is the API to add any html content inside the domElement.
And the html content can be returned from the javascript function in string format.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="container">
</div>

<script> function getHTMLContent() {
return "<h2>Nothing here</h2>";

}</script>

<script>
document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = getHTMLContent();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Jquery answer: Instead of `.innerHTML` we have `.append` in jquery. This also takes string as parameter. And there is no difference in the way we call the javascript function.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  function getHTMLContent() {
return "<h2>Nothing here</h2>";
}

$("#container").append(getHTMLContent());
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And regarding your doubt on function() and $function()..

```
$(function() { ... });
```

is just jQuery short-hand for

```
$(document).ready(function() { ... });
```

It gets called automatically once the page is ready.

But in javascript when you declare `function()`, this is not called by itself. You have to explicitly call it.

Comment: thank you that was exactly what I am looking for. If you can provide the jQuery one inside your answer I will mark it as accepted

Comment: is there a difference between "function" and '$(function()" in terms of storing HTML inside of it?

Comment: @DimitriBostrovich 
I have added jquery answer and the difference between function and $(function()) too.

Answer (score 0):

```
function nothing(){
  $(".container").append('nothing');
}
```

Comment: i dont think thats what I am looking for. I want to store the HTML inside a jquery function so that I can call upon it later to append the contents inside of it. that way if i need the same HTML multiple times, i dont have to copy/paste the same code. I can just use the function